# Navigation with Jetpack Compose - navigagte to another graph

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation-graph

I'm pretty new to the Navigation Component AND to Compose.

I have a first **Activity1** (containing 3 fragments) with a **Graph1**:

**Activity1:**

```
setContent {
    Theme {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = { ... },
            bottomBar = { ... }
        ) { innerPadding
            Activity1NavigationGraph(navController = navController, startDestination = "home")
         }
    }
}
// graph1
@Composable
fun Activity1NavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController, startDestination: String) {
    NavHost(navController) {
        composable("home") {
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable("lessons") {
            LessonsScreen()
        }
        composable("settings") {
            SettingsScreen()
        }
}
```

I have a second Activity **Activity2** containing two fragments with a **Graph2**:

**Activity2:**

```
setContent {
    Theme {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = { ... },
            bottomBar = { ... }
        ) { ...
            Activity2NavigationGraph(navController = navController, startDestination = "list")
         }
    }
}
// graph2
@Composable
fun Activity2NavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController, startDestination: String) {
    NavHost(navController) {
        composable("list") {
            ListScreen()
        }
        composable("details") {
            DetailsScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

I have a button in the Fragment having with the **HomeScreen** Composable, when clicking on it, I want to redirect the user to the **Activity2** with the **Graph2**.

I can use startActivity, but I want to use Navigation Component.

I saw that there are Nested Graphs, but this seems to be only to separate parts of the same graph, so that it doesn't become too complex, and not really for use another graph.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can not navigate to activity using Navigation Coponents so you have only one option is to use startActivity to navigate to activity2

Comment: You can do it using navigation component with XML.

Comment: You can check more https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started.

Comment: This is navigation using XML, and I managed to achieve this using XML. But I can't find the same thing with compose

Comment: But the compose is mostly a single activity application.

Comment: Not necessarily from what I saw. Each activity has its graph and composable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a startActivity...

Seems like it's the only solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).